# Strict mode for DateTime::createFromFormat()

Tags: php, datetime

```
$format = 'dmy';
echo DateTime::createFromFormat($format, '882200')->format($format);
```

Above code outputs `271201` (instead of `882200`) as it does following: 88 days + 22 months + 0 Years

Seems strange to convert a dateString through a format to a date - but when converting it back to the same format it gives something else.

Is there a strict mode that throws an Exception or returns `false`?

Comment: Actually the date converts to `2001-12-27 10:14:08` (UTC time).  So it's not 88 days + 22 months + 0 years.  What are you expecting the output to be?

Comment: @Martin I would expect `DateTime::createFromFormat($format, '882200')` to throw an exception/false, therefor I am asking for a strict mode which would check that there does not exist a day 88 and a month 22 in the Gregorian calendar

Answer (score 3):

You must do that yourself. Use the [getLastErrors()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-get-last-errors.php) method to check if the parsed Date is valid.

```
$format = 'dmy';
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, '882200');

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($dt->getLastErrors());
```

Output:

```
array(4) {
  ["warning_count"]=>
  int(1)
  ["warnings"]=>
  array(1) {
    [6]=>
    string(27) "The parsed date was invalid"
  }
  ["error_count"]=>
  int(0)
  ["errors"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
```